# Error Java heap space

Tags: java

En mi aplicación web, me salta este error, que hace que tenga que reiniciar el servidor:

```
13:08:13,508 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/Particulares].[spring-servlet]] (http-/10.199.97.50:8043-26) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet spring-servlet threw exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:133) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:180) [commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
        at org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.clone(SerializationUtils.java:82) [commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
        at com.ibc.part.component.Filtros.filtra(Filtros.java:54) [classes:]
        at com.ibc.part.mvc.SaldosController.index(SaldosController.java:62) [classes:]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor304.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
```

y el código al que hace referencia:

```
public PosicionGlobal2 filtra(PosicionGlobal2 pg, FiltroTarjeta filtro, boolean ctaEmpresa) throws CuentasEmptyException {

    PosicionGlobal2 clon = SerializationUtils.clone(pg);

    for(Iterator<Bkft07> it=clon.getBkft07s().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

        Bkft07 t07 = it.next();


        for(Iterator<Bkft08> it2=t07.getBkft08s().iterator(); it2.hasNext();) {

            Bkft08 t08 = it2.next();

            //Si no lo quiero....
            if (!this.getEstadoTarjeta(t08).equals(filtro) && !filtro.equals(FiltroTarjeta.TODAS)){
                it2.remove();
            }

        }

        //Si la cuenta esta vacia....
        //Si no queremos cuentas de empresa...
        if (t07.getBkft08s().isEmpty() || (!ctaEmpresa && t07.getIndnomemp().intValue()==1)){
            it.remove();
        }

    }

    if (clon.getBkft07s().isEmpty()) throw new CuentasEmptyException();

    return clon;
}
```

Según el error, la línea 54 es donde se clona un objeto, que contiene un array de una entity de hibernate.

¿Alguna forma de evitar el error o evitar hacer el clone del objeto?

Comment: Hola, puedes agregar el archivo de configuracion de Spring. ?

Comment: y donde se realiza la clonación???

Comment: @Elenasys en `PosicionGlobal2 clon = SerializationUtils.clone(pg);`, la primera línea del método.

Comment: Solución práctica: aumenta la memoria. Si el problema persiste: no utilices el método `SerializationUtils#clone`, busca una forma de realizar la copia profunda (deep copy) del objeto. en cuestión. Al parecer es un objeto muy pesado en memoria. Si el objeto no tiene muchos campos, te recomiendo crear un constructor de copia manual. Si es muy pesado, te recomiendo crear el constructor de copia manual pero donde algunos de los campos que necesites copiar los realices con `SerializationUtils#clone`, sabiendo que dichos objetos son suficientemente ligeros.

Comment: El problema está en cuántas instancias de clases creas y no liberas oportunamente. Simplemente se agota el espacio que definiste para la ejecución del servidor. Puedes hacer profiling con herramientas como Flight recorder (que viene en el Oracle JDK) *no hacerlo en producción por restricciones de licencia*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final el problema era que se clonaba una entity que a su vez, contenía otras entities y una de ellas tenia 2 campos blob con imágenes, y esta clonación siempre se hacía al hacer login, por lo que llenaba la memoria y el recolector de basura no daba abasto.

Esos campos blob son innecesarios en la aplicación, por lo que ya no los cargo, y no me como la memoria.

Answer (score 3):

Puede tratar de aumentar la memoria para la `JVM` por ejemplo algo asi `-Xmx1024m` , usted cuenta con un fichero para la asignación de memoria como servidor `setenv.sh`, podría tratar algo así `"CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m"`.

Busca algún fichero de configuración para su entorno y como ampliar la memoria , como por ejemplo este:

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh  
 set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M
```

O puede ser este otro:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M"
```

Puede mirar estos links para obtener mas información:

[Configuración](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40518_01/integrator.311/integrator_install/src/cli_ldi_server_config.html)

[Tomcat](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/)

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si no se puede aumentar la memoria por X motivos? ¿Qué debería hacerse en esos casos?

Comment: Generalmente ese error se debe a motivos de programación, donde se instancian muchos objetos y por algun motivo el garbage collector no da a basto, y la memoria colapsa, seguramente en  el log tendrás mas información util de la fuga de memoria, puedes editar y adjuntar el archivo de log ?

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar esa excepción, si estás usando JUnit y Spring intenta añadir esto en cada clase de tests:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
```