# Duda con bucle for para hallar múltiplos de mútiplos

Tags: java

Es mi primera vez por aquí, os comento mi duda: tengo que hacer un programita para que me obtenga del 1 al 1000000 aquellos que sean múltiplos de 100 y una vez obtenga esos múltiplos de 100, hallar dentro de ese rango, los que son múltiplos de 5, es decir, si me dice que el 100 es el primer múltiplo, pues entre 1 y 100 obtener los múltiplos de cinco, si el 200 es múltiplo de 100, entre el 1 y el 200, etc, así hasta 1000000. Tengo este código:

```
public class EjercicioMultiplos3 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int inicio = 1;
            int fin = 100000;

            int dividecien=100;
            int dividecinco= 5;

            for (int indice = inicio; indice <= fin; indice++) {

                if (indice % dividecien == 0) {

                    System.out.println("El número " + indice + " es divisible entre 100");

                    for (int cinco = 0; cinco <= indice; cinco++) {

                        if (cinco % dividecinco == 0) {

                            System.out.println("El número " + cinco + " es divisible entre 5");

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }
```

El problema viene que si la variable fin la inicio como 1000 me lo hace bien, si la inicio como 10000 también, pero si ya le meto un 100000 la consola entra en bucle infinito y de ahí no pasa. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: me da la sensacion que es el segundo bucle el que te genera el conflicto y que podrias ahorrartelo con un `if(indice%5==0)` lo he hecho un poco de cabeza y no estoy muy seguro

Comment: si al aumentar el numero la consonla entra en bucle quizas sea falta de ram y por eso peta porque necesita mas memoria para tanto numero

Comment: No creo que sea falta de RAM, tengo 16 GB de RAM vamos no creo que tenga problemas en eso, no?

Comment: @NicolasOñate si lo hago de la forma que tu me dices, es cierto que lo ejecuta bien, pero me muestra por ejemplo si 200 es divisible entre 100, me muestra los divisibles de 5 del 100 al 200, pero necesito que sea del 1 al 200, o del 1 al 300, así con cada caso

Comment: No comprendo bien tu duda, deseas que recorra un millón y que vaya obteniendo sus multiplos de 100, y cada vez que obtengas un multiplo, que vuelva a empezar hasta ese multiplo para obtener los multiplos de 5?

Comment: @NicolasOñate exacto, ese sería el cometido del ejercicio, un poco lioso pero lo has explicado bien.

Comment: Tu problema puede ser que int se te queda corto para esas cantidades y necesitas usar `double` o `long`, tambien puede ser que tarde mucho mas en hacer el calculo, ya que tiene que empezar de nuevo unas cuantas veces, puede provocar tambien un gasto excesivo de memoria como decia @carlosdiaz ya que son muchos calculos en muy poco tiempo, tal vez haciendole dormir unos milisegundos con un sleep te solucione el problema

Comment: Creo que el planteamiento no es correcto, porque cada vez que encuentres un multiplo por ejemplo 100 se calcula de 1 a 100 los multiplos de 5, y luego si encuentro 200 se calculan de 1 a 200 los multiplos de 5, entonces el programa habrá mostrado 2 veces los multiplos de 5  entre 1 y 100 y así sucesivamente con cada multiplo de 100 creo que por ahí es la duda de @Nicolas Oñate. Yo he ejecutado tu codigo con 100000 y se ejecuto por completo en 7 sec, memoria consume prácticamente cero y procesador me un 30%.

Comment: En realidad el código está bien, el inconveniente es que hay que procesar mucha información y se demora, mi computadora tiene 8 GB de Ram, y se ha demorado por 100000, 5 min; me imagino que si se espera mas tiempo se ejecutara completamente, claro que cada vez que va aumentando va a tener mas registros por cada múltiplo de 100

Comment: @mhplur voy a probar a dejarlo un rato con 1000000 a ver que ocurre, pero yo creía que esto era instantaneo y por eso pensé que era un bucle infinito

Comment: bucle infinito es distinto a tarda una eternidad en ejecutarse.. que es lo que esta pasando aca.. el segundo for se puede mejorar muchisimo y acelerar haciendo for (int cinco = 0; cinco <= indice; cinco+5) {

                            System.out.println("El número " + cinco + " es divisible entre 5");

                        } Ya que todo multiplo de 5 termina en 0 o 5 y ademas asi se recorren menos numeros ;)

Comment: cuando lo dejo ejecutando un rato, eclipse me acaba dando un error y en detalles me dice: Java heap scape, ¿a que es debido?

Comment: Podrías aumentar la memoria para la JVM, para que no suceda eso, aqui una publicación que te podría ayudar [Error Java heap space](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4916/error-java-heap-space)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no es un bucle infinito, más bien es un método que hace demasiadas operaciones.

Puedes probar si te estás saliendo de rango de esta forma:

```
   int fin = 100000;
   int inicio = fin -100;
```

Esto tardará mucho menos.

Y por otro lado, puedes cambiar el método que imprime el detalle para ver si el índice está ciclado o realmente avanzando:

```
  System.out.println("Indice:"+indice+"El número " + cinco + " es divisible entre 5");
```

Comment: Al final lo he dejado en 1000 de tope y si que me lo hace, comprobé efectivamente lo de añadir el número de indice y si que estaba continuado, por lo que simplemente era que tenían que hacer una burrada de operaciones y tardaba bastante.